# Is it possible to run method main via Maven if the class with this main is in project?

Tags: java, maven

There is my POM

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.package.Separator</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I am running `$ mvn package`  and getting `class not found exception : org.package.Separator`
is it possible to run it somehow?

I have solved this issue by separating pom to another module but it is just interesting now - is it possible to do it in

Comment: Looks like your given class is not in the project...(Why using an old version: 1.3.2 is the current version).

Comment: plugins have dependencies too. maybe you need to add the artifact the class with the main method is in into those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because plugin doesn't have current module compiled classes on classpath. You can use this config option to add them to classpath:

```
<additionalClasspathElements>
  <classpathElement>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classpathElement>
</additionalClasspathElements>
```

Here are more docs about the topic:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#additionalClasspathElements

**Please keep in mind that above config option was added in 1.3 version.**